# wordpress Front page still showing up an old one

Tags: wordpress

I changed the front page design and content, but the website is still showing the old one. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> only gets me the new page. And it happens every time I enter the site. I tried other computers too and the same, an old version.  It happens on other pages too.

The [site](http://b24online.net/betisinay/):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think some server side cache are enabled for your site. While I test your url with caching checker then it says server level caches are enabled. please contact your server admin

Answer (score 2):

There are two common causes for this issue. The first one is your browser cache. Sometimes your browser will show you a cached copy of your website instead of showing the new one. To resolve this issue, you need to simply hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in Mac) buttons on your keyboard to reload the page.

The second and most likely cause of this issue is poorly configured WordPress caching plugin. If you are using a cache plugin, then check it's settings and most of the plugin provide an option to exclude home page from caching. Please activate it.

more details can be available here 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-website-not-updating-right-away/

Comment: Not working. I wrote before it happens on other computer too, so its not my browser cache. Even after using CTRL + F5 when I reload the page I get the older version. And I don't have a cache plugin.

Comment: Hi I think some server side cache are enabled for your site. While I test your url with caching checker then it says server level caches are enabled.

Comment: I contacted the host - bluehost and it was a server cache problem. They solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Adding it as an answer then.. Later someone can use this solution